# SurveyMonkey API - Unable to post to "NPS Survey"

Tags: json, ajax, api, post, surveymonkey

I am using the SurveyMonkey API to post to a survey collector. All the data posts correctly EXCEPT the NPS answer, so the rest of the post is structured correctly. The API documentation is light on the response pattern for the way an NPS question is set up, requiring choice_id and row_id for single choice selections. I have searched here and elsewhere online and found no posts. Support says they cannot help with API questions and directed me back here...Any ideas what I have wrong?

The UI sending the post is sending the correct question ID, choice ID and row ID in the POST, but the NPS records as a 0 no matter what is the choice_id.

EDIT: My curl with API details redacted, returns a success and posts to the survey as well:

curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:bearer LONG_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors/90409963/responses?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY -d '{"pages":[{"id":"251789828","questions":[{"id":"1007849545","answers":[{"text":"77008"}]},{"id":"1007851127","answers":[{"text":"email"}]},{"id":"1004286916","answers":[{"text":"9"}]},{"id":"1004287193","answers":[{"text":"04"}]},{"id":"1004245087","answers":[{"row_id":"10503659035","choice_id":"10503659050"}]}]}]}'

Here is my JSON blob for the POST, the problem is posting the 5th question, ID 1004245087. I have validated the JSON using http://jsonlint.com/, no basic syntax issues. I can't find any examples

```
{
    "pages": [{
        "id": "251789828",
        "questions": [{
            "id": "1007849545",
            "answers": [{
                "text": "77777"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "1007851127",
            "answers": [{
                "text": "email"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "1004286916",
            "answers": [{
                "text": "9"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "1004287193",
            "answers": [{
                "text": "04"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "1004245087",
            "answers": [{
                "choice_id": "10503659050",
                "row_id": "10503659035"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

The GET for details about this question return, (excerpted with URLs removed):

```
{
"answers": {
    "rows": [{
        "visible": true,
        "text": "",
        "position": 1,
        "id": "10503659035"
    }],
    "choices": [{
        "description": "Not at all likely",
        "weight": -100,
        "id": "10503659039",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "Not at all likely - 0",
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": -100,
        "id": "10503659045",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "1",
        "position": 2
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": -100,
        "id": "10503659050",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "2",
        "position": 3
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": -100,
        "id": "10503659055",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "3",
        "position": 4
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": -100,
        "id": "10503659059",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "4",
        "position": 5
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": -100,
        "id": "10503659063",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "5",
        "position": 6
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": -100,
        "id": "10503659066",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "6",
        "position": 7
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": 0,
        "id": "10503659070",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "7",
        "position": 8
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": 0,
        "id": "10503659073",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "8",
        "position": 9
    }, {
        "description": "",
        "weight": 100,
        "id": "10503659077",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "9",
        "position": 10
    }, {
        "description": "Extremely likely",
        "weight": 100,
        "id": "10503659082",
        "visible": true,
        "is_na": false,
        "text": "Extremely likely - 10",
        "position": 11
    }]
},
"visible": true,
"headings": [{
    "heading": "How likely is it that you would recommend this class to a friend or colleague?"
}],
"position": 5,
"validation": null,
"id": "1004245087",
"forced_ranking": false
```

}

Comment: The payload you put looks exactly correct, can you try a cURL request or some other request tool to verify it isn't the UI? Example: http://pastebin.com/Hnmp93Yj

Comment: @GeneralKandalaft I have been posting with curl and it responds as a success but no matter what I put as the choice_id it logs as a response of "0" on the NPS score question. It does not even reply with a failure. Adding the curl with API details redacted above.

Comment: sorry, is your last statement "Adding the curl with API details redacted above" saying that it is working for you now? Or you are still having issues?